# Where can I read more detailed descriptions of the badge requirements?

Tags: discussion

The descriptions of the **badge requirements** on the FAQ are a nice start, but I often **would like more detail about the specifics**.  For example, why is it that no one on academia.SE has earned the generalist badge?  It turns out, there is fine print saying that each of the top 40 tags on the site must have at least 200 questions (so, for us that will be quite a while).  It would be great if all of this fine print was collected on a single page somewhere.  Is it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is at [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) over on meta.stackoverflow.  I've had a number of questions about the internal workings of academia.SE and particularly badges.  I find that almost always the question has already been addressed at Stack Overflow, and a google query with the key word "stackexchange" (rather than "academia") is the way to go.

Comment: I'm posting this question and answer here in hopes of saving other users time slowly rediscovering what I slowly discovered.